# Saving returned XML data in PHP to an XML file

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file which requests xml data and displays it it the browser. The XML is displayed by:

```
$xmlString = constructPostCallAndGetResponse($endpoint, $item, $postCode, $dist);

$resp = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

echo htmlentities($xmlString);
```

How do I save the returned XML to an XML file on my server? Ive read alot about DOM but keep going in circles. Can anyone suggest a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to save to file, with your sinplexml-object just do...

```
$resp->asXML('file.xml');
```